# Explain the Behavior of DISTINCT COUNT(*)

Tags: sql

In answering another question a ran a query that gave me an unexpected result. It would be normal to combine COUNT and DISTINCT as COUNT(DISTINCT field) to get the number of non-null distinct values in field.

I also tried DISTINCT COUNT(field) expecting that to show me the "number of counts" which would be basically always be 1. But that is *not* what it does.

```
CREATE TABLE Bob (id INT)
INSERT INTO Bob VALUES (0),(0),(1),(NULL)

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM Bob 
--Result: 2
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Bob          
--Result: 3
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(id) FROM Bob
--Result: 3
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bob
--Result: 4
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM Bob
--Result: 4
```

Instead it looks as if the query engine simple ignores DISTINCT when used this way. I tested this against SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostGreSQL, and SQLite and the behavior is the same.

Here's the [SQL Server fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc1eb/2/0) is you are curious.

Can you explain the behavior based on the ANSI standard or some other historical convention? Or maybe my original expected behavior is simple flawed in some way.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(id) FROM Bob makes no sense. Count is a scaler and by definition its singular. So your 4 examples are really just 2: difference between Count(*) and COUNT(Distinct colname) in the presence of NULLs

Comment: @MitchWheat That's what I thought and why I was surprised when I saw the actual results. I was expecting it to be at best trivial and at worst invalid syntax, but instead all the engines seem happy to discard the DISTINCT in front of COUNT.

Comment: Well, the optimiser 'knows' that a count is a count and distinct is irrelevant, so simply disregards it. I don't see any mystery in that.

Comment: `DISTINCT` eliminates duplicate rows. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bob` yields one row, with one column that contains the value 4. Removing duplicate rows from that result set leaves you with that same single row.

Comment: @Wiseguy: I think that proves I simply had a flaw in my original thinking. My brain apparently cramped thinking about a DISTINCT COUNT(\*) as COUNT(DISTINCT COUNT(\*) which is a)wrong, b)dumb and c)invalid in mssql at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `first row` i mean:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM Bob
```

it means that `COUNT OF DISTINCT IDs` in this sample we got `0,0,1,null` it returns COUNT OF `0,1,null` but `null` can't count there for it returns `2`

in the `Second row`:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Bob
```

it means `COUNT OF IDs` in this sample it `0,0,1,null` but as i said `null` can't count and it returns `3`

in the `third row`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(id) FROM Bob
```

it means `DISTINCT COUNT OF IDs` but here it means `COUNT OF IDs`,if we use `Group by` and the count have got many results then it returns distinct of `COUNTs`,and here it returns `COUNT OF IDs` i mean `3`,this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c79da/3)** can give you better clues about it.

in the `fourth row`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bob
```

it means `COUNT OF ROWS` and here we got `4` rows.

in the `fifth row`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM Bob
```

it means `DISTINCT COUNT OF the ROWS` but with out the `Group by` it returns one value and there for that value is distinct too, it returns `4` here.

Comment: Yep. Plain as day once I ask the question and have people answer it. My brain got stuck. Unstuck now, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The query is actually working as intended, but it's a bit tricky to understand why at first.

The best way to see what is going on is by examining the query execution plan.

Take the Select Distinct Count first.  Reading the plan, from right to left, you should see a table scan, with 4 rows passing to the Stream Aggregate.  From there, you have one row passing to the Compute Scalar, which has a value of 4, and thus SQL outputs 4.

Now, look at Select Count(distinct id).  Again from right to left, you should see the table scan, with 4 rows passing to a **Sort**.  Before SQL can compute the distinct rows it needs to sort them, then pass the 2 rows to the Stream Aggregate, which passes a count of 2.

Comment: +1, especially since a man named Counts had answer a question about COUNT(). Thank you Mr. Counts. (Assuming that Counts is a surname, not a hobby statement.)

Comment: @KarlKieninger you can count on Mr Counts for any count related Query !